# Using the headphone button with the pi

Tags: audio

I would like to use the button on my headphones (the one that play/pauses on a phone) as an input on my pi. I understand that this may need an expansion/audio board. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely will need an expansion board that splits the 4 pin from the headphones to the gpio on the pi. Plus the audio coming off the pi's audioport. Depending on how well you can program for the pi you should be able to. The button on the headphone grounds the pin. And the device counts how many times its pressed in a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if a solution already existed, but apparently not. I can solder and code - and the knowledge of the button grounding the mic pin is very helpful.

Comment: As to my knowledge there isn't a pre-made board. But if you design something that works well you could probably make a little money off it.

Comment: NB: I have [these](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/3047022.htm?CMPID=GS001&_$ja=cgid:12488198090|tsid:59158|cid:200217410|lid:107254893410|nw:g|crid:54924971930|rnd:860171054788764720|dvc:c|adp:1o2|bku:1) and they seem to connect the button through 3 ohms - although this is only through a very quick multimeter test and not conclusive.