# Xiaomi MiKey in 3.5mm port

Tags: pi-3, switches

I have bought a [Xiaomi MiKey](http://www.dx.com/nl/p/xiaomi-dustproof-3-5mm-plug-one-click-shortcut-key-orange-322539) which enables me to trigger events with my mobile phone. It is a 3.5mm jack with a button, you can configure the button to do whatever you want with an app or you can write your own app to do it.

I'm also working on a project with a Raspberry Pi 3, currently I'm using a toggle switch to toggle between setup-mode and production-mode. I thought maybe I can use the Xiaomi MiKey to toggle between those modes.

I'm not really familiar with this kind of buttons and with 3.5mm ports so I hope you could tell me if this is possible or not and push me a bit more in the right direction. I've found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/using-the-headphone-button-with-the-pi) that wants something that is a bit comparable to what I'm trying to achieve. Is the expansion board that splits the jack to gpio something [like this](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/hifiberry-dac-plus-3-5mm-jack-met-spacers) or isn't that the way to go for me at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do some soldering (which is a single-wire job), then yes, you can use it with your Pi.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A08IrJ3ECuA&list=WL&index=2) shows you how. Basically you wire the 3.5mm ground to pin 5 on the GPIO header, then run [the script mentioned here](http://pie.8bitjunkie.net/retropie-shutdown-and-startup-switch-the-easy-way) (or write your own) to listen for the button press.

I think pin 5 also lets you start the Pi too, so it's a dual startup and shutdown button.